# ML.NET load Tensorflow model

Tags: c#, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, ml.net

I have built a model like this in python:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    #normalizer,
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(units=1)
])

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    loss='mean_absolute_error')

history = model.fit(
    train_features,
    train_labels,
    epochs=300,
    verbose=0,
    validation_split = 0.3)
```

and exported to a frozen graph like this (as stated [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27614#issuecomment-572877506)):

```
from tensorflow.python.framework.convert_to_constants import convert_variables_to_constants_v2

full_model = tf.function(lambda x: model(x))
full_model = full_model.get_concrete_function(
    tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype))

frozen_func = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(full_model)
frozen_func.graph.as_graph_def()

tf.io.write_graph(graph_or_graph_def=frozen_func.graph,
                  logdir="test",
                  name=f"test.pb",
                  as_text=False)
```

The model take a array of integers (length 2) as input:

```
input = np.array([12, 300])
input_for_pred = np.expand_dims(input,axis=0)
result = model.predict(input_for_pred)
print(result)
```

> [[2942.2483]]

The graph looks like this in Netron:
[image]
With this being the last (most bottom) "Identity" node:
[image]

Now that I have the model, I want to use it in ML.NET. I tried multiple tutorials / samples, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.transforms.tensorflowmodel.scoretensorflowmodel?view=ml-dotnet) is my current basis.
My code:

```
    public class TensorData
    {
        [ColumnName(@"x")]
        [VectorType(2)]
        public long[] input { get; set; }
    }

    public static TensorData[] GetTensorData()
    {
        return new TensorData[] { new() { input = new long[] { 0, 0 } }, new() { input = new long[] { 12, 10 } }, new() { input = new long[] { 12, 800 } } };
    }

    class OutputScores
    {
        [ColumnName(@"Identity")]
        public float[] output { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        var mlContext = new MLContext();
        var data = GetTensorData();
        var idv = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(data);
        using var model = mlContext.Model.LoadTensorFlowModel(@"path to model");
        var pipeline = model.ScoreTensorFlowModel(
            new[] { "Identity"},
            new[] { "x" }, addBatchDimensionInput: true);
        var estimator = pipeline.Fit(idv);
        var transformedValues = estimator.Transform(idv);
        var outScores = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<OutputScores>(transformedValues , reuseRowObject: false);
        foreach (var prediction in outScores)
        {
            //Error
        }
    }
```

This created an error when looping over outScores:
[image]

Unfortunately I can't find any solution to this. Do you have an idea?
If it helps, I have uploaded the model saved by TF aswell as the frozen one here:
https://easyupload.io/dp9kn5